# How to build more projects with gradle while the part which they share will be build only once?

Tags: java, gradle, build

I have three subprojects in my project. Each of them is executable web app. They share the same core module which **also** has its build.gradle script. Let's say its name is `shared-core`. Right now I have separate gradle.build and settings.gradle for each of them. So when I am trying to build all of them the core will get rebuilt thrice. But I would like to set up gradle script so the `shared-core` will get rebuilt only once.

I am really new to gradle so sorry if this is a dumb question but how can I do that ?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

```
root(main-project)
|
|-shared-core
|   |-build.gradle
|
|-sub-project-a
|   |-build.gradle
|
|-sub-project-b
|   |-build.gradle
|
|-sub-project-c
|   |-build.gradle
|
|-build.gradle
|-settings.gradle
```

Now on each subproject, you add dependency of shared-core as `compile project(':shared-core')`. You can find more details on [multi-project builds.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help I will check that out :).

Comment: Those 3 subprojects each of them has complicated build.gradle and settings.gradle. It is not that trivial for me to group it under common root. Can you help me what should I put to build.gradle and settings.gradle of root project so it will work ?

Comment: The build.gradle in subprojects can be as is with minor extraction to root build,gradle. However, you can have only one settings.gradle which will include subprojects and should be as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly (from the multiple settings.gradle files), you're building your projects as completely separate builds. Gradle has no knowledge of the relationships between these projects.

If you create a [multi-project build](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/), where each of your projects are sub-projects, and you make each `webapp` module depend on the `shared-core`, then Gradle will only build the `shared-core` project once in a single build.

You can still configure each `webapp` module as you like.

If you don't want to see all webapps in a single project, take a look at [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html), but setting up that is a bit more difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your help I will check that out :).